# JSON-PHP - выводит только один элемент.

Tags: php, массивы, json

Мой код:

```
$itog=json_decode($result3, true);
foreach ($itog as $out) {
echo "<tr>
        <td>".$i."</td>
        <td>".$out[$i]['document_id']."</td>
        </tr>";
        $i=$i+1; }
```

Данный код переберает данные и должен выводить в таблицу данные из массива. В массиве 20 элементов $itog[0],$itog[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwJzF.jpg) и т.д., но по факту выводит только один элемент и $i второго. Дальше перебор данных не идет. Как сделать полный перебор массива в моем случае? Спасибо.

[image: Итог]

Comment: покажите свою json строку $result3

Comment: @madfan41k https://pastebin.com/0Xbradrp сильно большой json, скинул по ссылке

Comment: @sflyer, так у Вас же сперва идет `"documents": [ ... ]`, а уже внутри этого то, что Вам надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ сделать - добавить `$itog['documents']`, так как все нужные Вам элементы находятся внутри `documents`.

```
$itog=json_decode($result3, true);
foreach ($itog['documents'] as $out) {
    echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i."</td>
                <td>".$out['document_id']."</td>
          </tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: В итоге прошло все 20 строк, но на вывод $out[$i]['document_id'] теперь ничего не выходит

Comment: @sflyer, уберите в `$out[$i]` индекс `$i`, он там ни к чему. Обновил. [Посмотрите на это.](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb29cc3e)

Comment: Действительно помогло, большое спасибо!

Comment: @sflyer, всегда пожалуйста:)

Comment: @sflyer, не балуйтесь галочкой, оставьте её здесь

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите по строке на документ, то и итерировать нужно документы:

```
$itog=json_decode($result3, true);
foreach ($itog['documents'] as $i => $out) {
echo "<tr>
  <td>".$i."</td>
  <td>".$out['document_id']."</td>
</tr>";
}
```